# Powershell - Error Handling (Try/Catch) Best Practice

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to figure out the "most right" way to use Try/Catch error handling in my Powershell scripts. One question I have is for a script like the following: ForEach file, I'm executing a Copy-Item, a Move-Item, then performing a function on a file. Would I do a try catch for each of the three commands? This doesn't seem right as I wouldn't want to continue if any any failed. Or would I use just one Try/Catch and add the -ErrorVariable parameter after each cmdlet then use some query logic in the Catch to determine which of the three commands error'd out? If so, how do I find out which ErrorVariable (CopyErr, MoveErr) was created?

Option One:

```
($hash = @(Get-ChildItem C:\DIR -Recurse -Include *.txt) | Where {$_.length -gt 0}) | ForEach-Object {
    Try {
        Copy-Item $_ -Destination C:\DIR2\ -Force -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable CopyErr
        Move-Item $_ -Destination C:\ARCHIVE\$($_.BaseName).$(Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss").txt -Force -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable MoveErr
        Start-Process SomeExternalProcess.exe -PassThru
    }
    Catch {
        "logic to determine which cmd failed"
    }
```

Option Two:

```
 ($hash = @(Get-ChildItem C:\DIR -Recurse -Include *.txt) | Where {$_.length -gt 0}) | ForEach-Object {
    Try {
        Copy-Item $_ -Destination C:\DIR2\ -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    Catch {
        "Copy Error"
    }
     Try {
        Move-Item $_ -Destination C:\ARCHIVE\$($_.BaseName).$(Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss").txt -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    Catch {
        "Move Error"
    }
     Try {
        Start-Process SomeExternalProcess.exe -PassThru
    }
    Catch {
        "Process Error"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not really having code issue. What you are asking for is an opinion. Asking for opinions will give you a wide rage of responses.

If what you have works for you, then, keep that. Yet, the real thing here is what kind of error(s) do you really want to catch.

Terminating / non-terminating / both?
… and at which stage …

There are no MS official best practices for PowerShell, but there are many offering up a position on the some items.

So, this is a broad topic so, really a challenge to give a simple code-based response.

BTW … Try/Catch - error handling in general is not a PowerShell specific thing. IT's been around for years in virtually every main programming language. So, referencing the guidance in other languages is also prudent.

See these:

> Best practices for exceptions
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions
>
> C# Exception Handling Best Practices
>
> https://stackify.com/csharp-exception-handling-best-practices
>
> Windows PowerShell
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/windows-powershell
>
> PowerShell Standard Library: Build single module that works across
>   Windows PowerShell and PowerShell Core
>   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2018/08/06/powershell-standard-library-build-single-module-that-works-across-windows-powershell-and-powershell-core
>
> PowerShellPracticeAndStyle
>
> https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle
>
> PowerShell scripting best practices
>
> https://martin77s.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/powershell-scripting-best-practices
>
> Powershell - Recommended coding style
>
> https://lazywinadmin.com/2011/06/powershell-recommended-coding-style.html
>
> What is the recommended coding style for PowerShell?
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025989/what-is-the-recommended-coding-style-for-powershell

See also:

> How using try catch for exception handling is best practice
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973642/how-using-try-catch-for-exception-handling-is-best-practice

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about answering to an accepted answer.

Here what works for me, moving 25k folders:

```
Move-Item -Path '001DAB77' -Destination '..\..\Archive\001DAB77'
$errorCheckFine = $?
( (Get-Date -Format G) + '> ' + $errorCheckFine + ':001DAB77') | Add-Content '..\..\Archive\move.log'
```

and next folder

```
Move-Item -Path '001DAB78' -Destination '..\..\Archive\001DAB78'
$errorCheckFine = $?
( (Get-Date -Format G) + '> ' + $errorCheckFine + ':001DAB78') | Add-Content '..\..\Archive\move.log'
```

The output in the move.log file:

> 2024-01-30 08:46:06> True:001DAB78

Yes, there is a better way to fetch all 24k folders, using Import-Csv and foreach, but this is not the topic here.